# Golang auto referencing, not always possible to get the address of a value

Tags: pointers, go, types, reference

I am a newbie in Golang world. I was trying to understand the concept of **auto referencing**.

My confusion related to the below program? what is the difference between first and the second

1. first line in function main

```
age(20).print()
```

2. second and third line

```
myAge := age(20)
myAge.print()
```

Full program below:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type age uint8

func (a *age) print() {
  fmt.Println(a)
}


func main() {
  age(20).print() // this line throws error

  // however, the below line works properly
  myAge := age(20)
  myAge.print()
}
```

Please help to understand the difference between the two approaches. I was in an assumption they both are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a convenience provided by the compiler. As mentioned in the [calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) section of the spec:

> If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand
> for (&x).m()

This is elaborated on in the [method Pointers vs Values](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values) section of Effective Go.

To determine what is addressable, you can refer to the [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) section of the spec. Specifically:

> ... either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing
> operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an
> array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to
> the addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly
> parenthesized) composite literal.

Going back to your example, `(a *age) print()` is a pointer receiver on `age`. This means that the full call on an `age` variable is `&<expr>.print()`. This can only be done if `expr` is addressable. Looking at the addressability requirements:

- `myAge` is a variable, it is addressable.
- `age(20)` is a type conversion and is not addressable.

Ignoring the method call, you can check the addressability easily by trying the following:

```
_ = &age(20)     // cannot take the address of age(20)
myAge := age(20)
_ = &myAge       // works fine
```

Comment: Thank @Marc. Really useful insite. Also thanks for pointing me to the right place in go docs.

Comment: Methods defined with a pointer receiver (t *T) can be called only on pointers of type T. However, methods defined with a value receiver (t T) can be called on both values and pointers of that type.
Cheatsheet: Receiver (t T) works on T and *T, Receiver (t *T) works only on *T.